# SQL Aninhado duvida

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Estou utilizando esse *SELECT*, porém agora preciso buscar na tabela de clientes os campos (ex: `cli_clifone` e `cli_clicontato`) , como eu posso incluir para trazer essas informações no *SELECT* abaixo, estou tentando porém só me retorna erro:

```
SELECT cli_cdcli, cli_razsoc
 From
 (
 SELECT cli_cdcli, cli_razsoc FROM vw_os_finalizada_cliente
 Union
 SELECT cli_cdcli, cli_razsoc FROM vw_titrec_aberto_cliente
 ) AS ConCli
 GROUP BY ConCli.cli_cdcli
 ORDER BY ConCli.cli_razsoc, ConCli.cli_cdcli
```

Comment: Como tentou? Qual foi o erro retornado?

Comment: Não seria só mudar a primeira linha para `SELECT cli_cdcli, cli_razsoc, cli_clifone, cli_clicontato`?

Comment: Query : SELECT cli_cdcli, cli_razsoc, cli_clifone  From  (  SELECT cli_cdcli, cli_razsoc FROM vw_os_finalizada_cliente  Union  SELECT ...
Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'cli_clifone' in 'field list'

Comment: eu nao consigo porque ela não esta na views e nao posso incluir ela na views !

Comment: preciso incluir um SELECT somente para o fone e para o contato do cliente junto aos SELECT abaixo porem não estou conseguindo encaixar a sintaxe.

Comment: usar as views pra isso é muito ruim ein... o certo seria executar o select direto na tabela dos clientes, da forma que está vai precisar fazer um join com esta para buscar os outros campos

Comment: Porem eu preciso ter as views porque são campos especificos.

Comment: ou você pensa que precisa... nem mesmo esse sub-select e group by são necessários...

Comment: peguei esse programa com essa estrutura, para dar manutenção e solicitaram que eu acrescentasse esses campos o que voce sugere fazer ?

Comment: cada caso é um caso, inicialmente eu eliminaria a view... mas só dá pra saber o que fazer, analisando o caso especifico... se quiser fazer apenas uma gambiarra... basta colocar o join com a tabela de cliente e buscar os campos

Comment: a minha ideia a principio foi colocar um join para a tabela de cliente porem eu nao estou conseguindo encaixa-lo voce sabe como posso fazer ?

Comment: Qual é o nome dessa tabela de cliente e quais são os campos que lá existem?

Comment: a tabela se chama : cliente   e os campos dela é : 
cli_nmcontato, cli_nrdddfn1, cli_fone1, cli_nrdddfn2, cli_fone2, cli_nrdddfn3, cli_fone3, cli_nrdddfax, cli_fax

Comment: Adiciona um inner join por fora de tudo ligando com o id cliente que vem da view, e adiciona as novas colunas dessa tabela nova.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo pouco que você informou eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT cli_cdcli, cli_razsoc, A.cli_clifone, A.cli_clicontato
From
(
SELECT cli_cdcli, cli_razsoc FROM vw_os_finalizada_cliente
Union
SELECT cli_cdcli, cli_razsoc FROM vw_titrec_aberto_cliente
) AS ConCli
INNER JOIN (tabela de cliente original) as A ON (A.cli_cdcli=ConCli.cli_cdcli)
GROUP BY ConCli.cli_cdcli
ORDER BY ConCli.cli_razsoc, ConCli.cli_cdcli, A.cli_clifone, A.cli_clicontato
```

Como você já tem os clientes corretos através das view e não pode adicionar as outras informações, acredito que seria a forma mais fácil.